# Getting an error while installing webdriverio to the visual studio on MAC

Tags: npm-install, webdriver-io, npm-package

Installing wdio packages:

- @wdio/local-runner@latest
- @wdio/cucumber-framework@latest
- wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter
- wdio-chromedriver-service
- chromedriver
  npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
  npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! While resolving: my-new-project@undefined
  npm ERR! Found: @wdio/cucumber-framework@8.4.0
  npm ERR! node_modules/@wdio/cucumber-framework
  npm ERR!   dev @wdio/cucumber-framework@"8.4.0" from the root project
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
  npm ERR! peer @wdio/cucumber-framework@"7.x" from wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter@4.4.3
  npm ERR! node_modules/wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter
  npm ERR!   dev wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter@"*" from the root project
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
  npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
  npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! For a full report see:
  npm ERR! /Users/users/.npm/_logs/2023-03-01T05_40_20_365Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/users/.npm/_logs/2023-03-01T05_40_20_365Z-debug-0.log
⚠️ An unknown error happened! Please retry installing dependencies via "npm i --save-dev @wdio/local-runner@latest @wdio/cucumber-framework@latest wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter wdio-chromedriver-service chromedriver"

Error: unknown
✔ Success!

Creating a WebdriverIO config file...
✔ Success!

Autogenerating test files...
✔ Success!

Adding "wdio" script to package.json.
✔ Success!

Successfully setup project at /Users/users/Desktop/Projects/webdriverio

Join our Matrix community and instantly find answers to your issues or queries. Or just join and say hi !
 https://matrix.to/#/#webdriver.io:gitter.im

Visit the project on GitHub to report bugs  or raise feature requests :
 https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio

To run your tests, execute:
$ cd /Users/users/Desktop/Projects/webdriverio
$ npm run wdio

⚠️  Ups, something went wrong: Error calling: npx wdio config!
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/users/Desktop/Projects/webdriverio
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c create-wdio .

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/users/.npm/_logs/2023-03-01T05_38_58_953Z-debug-0.log
users@users-MacBook-Pro webdriverio %

wanted to install webdriverio in visual studio to my project for automation using javascript, but getting this ERROR.
Please help me here, as i am new to this.
THANK YOU